# AWS iOS App crashes

Tags: ios, swift3, aws-mobilehub

My AWS iOS App crashes, when I converted my code to Swift 3.

It crashes in the following line:

[image]

**EDIT**

I think the problem lies within the following method:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]?)
    -> Bool {
        return AWSMobileClient.sharedInstance.didFinishLaunching(application, withOptions: launchOptions!)
}
```

I get the same error message here, because I forcefully have to unwrap launchOptions

Comment: Does `resumeSession` have a return value?